# JQuery capturing click event on nested a tag in li

Tags: jquery, onclick

I'm having a problem with capturing a JQuery onclick event on a nested a tag within a UL

```
<ul class="paginate">
<li>>1</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.xxx.co.uk/xxx/" onclick="ajaxPage('2',true,'left'); return false;">2</a>
```

I've tried a number of ways to capture if the user clicks on the a tag, but nothing seems to work;

```
$('.paginate li').click(function(){ 
    alert('Caught page');
});

$('ul.paginate li').click(function(){ 
    alert('Caught page');
});

$('.paginate li a').click(function(){ 
    alert('Caught page');
});
```

Can you help?

Comment: Well, the first `li` has a broken HTML tag and the second one is hijacking the click event and returning `false`.  Maybe those are the culprits?

Comment: My fault the broken li is a typo

Comment: can I override the false on the second li?

Comment: You mean can you remove it?  Sure.  I can't guarantee it won't have an effect outside of the code shown, of course.

Comment: Why don't you remove the inline event ?

Comment: Also, when does this JavaScript code run?  The first posted answer below is implying that the DOM might not be loaded yet when you're trying to bind the event.  Consider using the jQuery `.on()` to address this.

Comment: Found my other problem. The alert works now, but inside I want it to call a method on delay setTimeout, but this gets cancelled as the it triggers the return false from the a tag :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('ul.paginate li').click(function(e) { 
       alert('Caught page');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me once you clean up the html:

http://jsfiddle.net/4s6rv/

```
<ul class="paginate">
<li>1</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.xxx.co.uk/xxx/" onclick="ajaxPage('2',true,'left'); return false;">2</a>
</li>
</ul>

$('.paginate li a').click(function(){ 
    alert('Caught page');
});
```

Comment: Found my other problem. The alert works now, but inside I want it to call a method on delay setTimeout, but this gets cancelled as the it triggers the return false from the a tag :-(